# iOS: Reading speed in Main Bundle vs Documents Folder

Tags: ios, iphone, performance

I was wondering if there is any substantial difference (in speed, mainly) between reading from the main bundle vs doing it from the documents folder. Any documentation regarding this is more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: They are both directories of files on the same filesystem so I would have thought there was no difference at all.

Comment: @Droppy Not necessarily. The app bundle is read-only. Documents isn't. iOS 8 changes the sandbox layout. The Documents folder may not be a subfolder of the resource bundle like in the past. So it is possible there is a (tiny) difference. The only way to know is to actually perform lots of real tests on real devices.

Comment: @rmaddy So you think there is a possibility the app bundle and the Documents folder are on different filesystems?

Comment: @Droppy I haven't looked to be 100% sure. Who know what iOS 9 will bring or other future updates. I'm just saying that it might be possible and not to make any assumptions. The OP just needs to perform real tests.